# Creating a reset button for each input

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 or more input type that have clear (reset) button for each field,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="text1" class="dummytext" />
<button type="button" class="clear-btn">Clear</button>

<input type="text" name="text1" class="dummytext" />
<button type="button" class="clear-btn">Clear</button>
```

As I far as I do with jQuery, every time I press the one of the Clear button, every input also being cleared. I just want to clear input type related with each Clear button. Any help?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Can you show us your code please? We can fix it then.

Comment: Nevermind, already answered by Joseph, thanks anyway. ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) method to get the related `input`:

```
$('.clear-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().val('');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq3Vg/

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's `prev()` method for getting the `input` DOM object and set value to empty
[JSBin link](http://jsbin.com/udupoc/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(".clear-btn").each(function (i) {
  $(this).on("click", function () {
    $("input[type='text']").eq(i).val('');
  });
});
```

with this, the clear button doesn't have to be necessarily just after (or before) the field but elsewhere.

See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4wnS/)**